# How to prevent duplicate results with angularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire

I have firebase db like this :

```
    "cardsList" : {
            "tok_1BVGrNCM8UWO9kaul5P0MoQa" : {
              "cardHolder" : "John",
              "expMonth" : 12,
              "expYear" : 2020,
              "number" : "42** **** **** **43",
              "pin" : 1234
            },
              "tok_7BTErNCM8UWO9kaul5P0MoQa" : {
              "cardHolder" : "Eliott",
              "expMonth" : 12,
              "expYear" : 2020,
              "number" : "44** **** **** **49",
              "pin" : 1234
            }
}
```

I get the results for each card in an array using this :

```
this.firebaseProvider.list('patientList/'+this.profileMember.idPatient+'/cardsList')
    .subscribe(cards=> cards.forEach(card=> {
      console.log(card.number)
      this.cardsList.push({'number': card.number})
      }))
```

In my html I show the result with :

```
<div *ngFor="let card of cardsList">
{{card.number}}
</div>
```

The problem is that I get duplicate result each time one value on the database is updated (ex: carHolder is updated)

Ex :
BEFORE THE UPDATE

```
42** **** **** **43
44** **** **** **49
```

AFTER THE UPDATE

```
42** **** **** **43
44** **** **** **49
42** **** **** **43
```

How to prevent this?

Any help is welcome.

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply avoid it just by converting `observable` to `promise` like below.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

this.firebaseProvider.list('patientList/'+this.profileMember.idPatient+'/cardsList').toPromise().then(cards=> cards.forEach(card=> {
    this.cardsList.push({'number': card.number})
}))
```

Comment: Hi,
It return : toPromise() is not a function. toPromise is not defined.

Comment: Thanks Sam !

Your solution is working.

I have one other question and maybe you can help me too ;-)

Comment: If I use this code : 
this.paymentList = this.firebaseProvider.list('patientList/'+this.profileMember.idPatient+'/paymentList')
  .map((cards) => {
    return cards.map(card => {
      return this.firebaseProvider.object('patientList/'+this.profileMember.idPatient+'/paymentList/'+card.$key)
})
  })

Is it a way to push the result into an array like :
this.cardsList.push(the results of paymentList) ?

Comment: I don't think above `code` will work due to the `async` nature of it. Hope you can put it as another question no? Then it'll have better visibility.